# Is there a way to reduce size of complex number?

Tags: matrix, complex, compile, packed-arrays

I would like to create huge matrices with hundreds of thousands of elements per side and I would like to use complex numbers in it for further processing by Mathematica functions. When I investigate size of some complex number `(1.001 + 1.001*I) // ByteCount`, it gives `56` bytes. When I use `PackedArray` one number has `16` bytes and I interpret it as two numbers with type double. Is there a way to reduce its size even more to get `8` bytes complexes (two floats) or are there another number types with `8` bytes that would behave like complex numbers? Would Compiling to C or similar help? Thanks.

Comment: Well, packing makes a difference (compare `ByteCount[{1.001 + 1.001 I, 2.001 + 1.002 I}]` vs. ``ByteCount[Developer`ToPackedArray[{1.001 + 1.001 I, 2.001 + 1.002 I}]]``) but otherwise I'm not sure what further gains you're expecting for an array of machine precision numbers.

Comment: In pure C, you could use single precision complex numbers with 8 bytes per number. As far as I know, single precision is not supported for MTensors by LibraryLink. Only the data type MImage allows for single precision reals (seemingly no complex numbers there). Have a look here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html As far as I can recall, also CUDALink and LibraryLink provide single precision data types. Then however, you have to get the data onto the graphics card and graphics memory is again very limited.

Comment: Where do your matrices come from? Are they sparse? Or do the have low rank? Why would you like to create that large matrics? Maybe you need only parts of them in memory while the rest can be left in mass storage?